# is using eval() to run the contents of an html attribute safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So i'm simply trying to mimic some angular syntax and create some functionality of my own where I can add an html attribute: m-click="navigate('/signup')" and then evaluate the javascript inside.

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.navigate = function(url) {
  console.log('go to: "' + url + '"');
};

$('[m-click]').on('click', function(item) {
  eval('$scope.' + $(this).attr('m-click'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button m-click="navigate('/signup');">
  Sign Up
</button>
```

What I'm wondering is:

- **is this how this is done with Angular and ng-click?**
- **Is there another way to do this?**
- **Is this safe, or is it prone to attacks?**

Comment: By itself, it's quite safe. Users will be eval'ing code in their browsers, which they already have full control over (including access to dev console). So as long as you don't put user input in those attributes, you should be good.

Comment: Angular has its own expression parser. It doesn't use eval.

Comment: Why not just `data-navigate="signup"`? Use a JS handler to evaluate it and call `navigate()`. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi this is just an example. customized functions would be the goal of this.

Comment: @JJJ do you have any links or anything that would explain how that works? I'm curious to see how it works!

Comment: https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+expression+parser)

Comment: @fjaxyu Why do you want to put customised functions in the markup?

Comment: @Bergi, I like the functionality and convenience of using Angular's syntax. ng-click="doThis()" or ng-click="doThat(obj)" is really convenient and makes it flexible.

Comment: If you like the functionality and convenience of using Angular's syntax, read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives). Most anything you want to do can be done in a safe way without using the [evil eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to do this?

If you split the arguments, you could do it without an `eval`:

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.navigate = function(url) {
  console.log('go to: "' + url + '"');
};

$('[m-click]').on('click', function(item) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var func = $this.attr('m-click');
  var to = $this.attr('m-to');
  $scope[func](to);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button m-click="navigate" m-to="/signup">
  Sign Up
</button>
```

> Is this safe, or is it prone to attacks?

Not directly, but `eval` is in general unsafe. If you make a mistake in another place, every script code could be injected.

Answer (score 0):

To write `m-click` as a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives):

```
app.directive("mClick", function() {
    return {
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on("click", function(event) {
                scope.$eval(attrs.mClick);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
     };
});
```

If you like the functionality and convenience of using Angular's syntax, read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives). Most anything you want to do can be done in a safe way without using the [evil eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!).